# Separate TLS Client Write and Server Write Keys in AES-CCM Mode

Tags: aes, tls, ccm

I am designing a system that uses TLS-like handshaking on a resource-constrained embedded system.  I have settled on AES-CCM mode for symmetric session encryption and authentication, allowing encryption and MAC to use the same key.  I would further like to combine the server write and client write keys into a single key for both directions because I would like to avoid having 2 expanded keys stored for each open session.

Nonce non-reuse in this case is achieved through a combination of a per-device ID and an incrementing frame counter, but I can also add an extra bit to differentiate client versus server writes at the nonce level, ensuring non-reuse of a nonce/key combination between both halves of the conversation.

Can anyone foresee a specific possible problem with doing this?

(PS: I am aware of the normal reason for separate encryption keys for each direction, and for separate MAC/encryption keys for modes other than CCM and GCM.  I am also most interested in specific possible problems, and would really like to avoid making a decision that would consume extra memory and degrade performance purely based on the vague/non-specific/unjustified/fear-motivated 'best-practices' that I've found so far.)